# Java: Best Practice for Declaration and Initialization

Tags: java, memory, reference, heap-memory, allocation

I do consider myself quite experienced in Java but there are still some minor basic things that I'm not really sure of.

I always try to write maintainable, easy readable code and aim for highest efficency.
For example I only call a "new"-Operator only when it is really needed.

That is because I don't want to allocate memory unnecessarily.
But what about supporting Variables?

Lots of people tend to declare a String just to assign some long ass method call like this:

String helper = Class.method1().method2(param).getter();

I always wonder if that doesn't allocate more memory than needed.
The getter returns a new Object already and now even more memory is allocated by referencing it in addition.
When I have use this getter more than once a helper string is convenient, but if it is needed only once wouldn't it be better to pass that method directly instead of declaring a new variable? 
Does this actually allocate memory to the heap?

Object a, b, c, d, e ,f , g, h, i, j ...;

I hope some more experienced Java guys than me can tell me how they handle basic stuff like this. thanks! :)

Comment: In your example, there'd be more memory used on the _stack_ but not the _heap_.  It's such a tiny amount that it's not worth worrying about.  What matters is that by giving the String a helpful name, you make your code slightly more self-documenting and therefore more readable.

Comment: "The getter returns a new Object already..." - No, it doesn't usually, if it just returns a reference to a member of the object it's called on, as is the case with most getter methods.

Comment: What's actually more important, is that `Class.method1().method2(param).getter()` is a blatant violation of the [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) (the principle of least knowledge), making the code tightly coupled to its dependencies and thus more hard to maintain.

Comment: "I always try to write maintainable, easy readable code and aim for highest efficency. For example I only call a "new"-Operator only when it is really needed." man.. this doesn't say anything. 
And "Class.method1().method2(param).getter();" OMG you'r working with monkeys? Did they ever read Clean Code ?

Answer (score 1):

**Does this actually allocate memory to the heap?**
No, it is allocated on the stack. Global variables are allocated on the heap.

When your method finishes it will return the allocated memoryspace it took from the stack, and the variable will no longer be of any concern.

**I always wonder if that doesn't allocate more memory than needed**
It will allocate memory on the stack for a reference to the variable. This reference is not needed if you pass the function as an argument. However, the function still has to be evaluated and it's returned value **will** be placed on the stack. If you declare a variable for it, a few extra writes and reads has to be performed, which should in most cases not be of any concern with respect to todays efficient computers.

Answer (score 0):

If the member can only be set via an accessor (a "setter" method), I prefer the first style. It provides a hint that the initialized value is the default upon construction.

If the member can be specified during construction, I generally pass the default value to an appropriate constructor from constructor with fewer parameters. For example,

```
final class Example {

  private final String name;

  Example() {
    this("My Example");
  }

  Example(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

}
```